# How to count the number of times a value appears in a 160Million by 2 dataframe - memory issues

Tags: r

I have a data frame that has 160M rows  and 2 columns(material name and price). I want to determine how many the frequency at which prices occur.

For example,

the price $10 was given 100 different times. I'd like to sort the values by largest occurrence to smallest occurs (example, $100 was given 1000 times)

There are 2,484,557 unique prices, so a "table" is not the most useful solution.

my issue is I'm dealing with memory issues.

Any suggestions how I can accomplish this?

Comment: Sounds like a database job.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a 2 GB data frame with 160M rows and about 3M unique prices:

```
set.seed(42)
n = 160E6
fake_data <- data.frame(material = sample(LETTERS, n, replace = TRUE),
                        price = sample(1:3E6, n, replace = TRUE))
```

I like `dplyr` syntax, but for large data with many groups, `data.table` and `collapse` offer much better performance.

We could use `dtplyr` to translate dplyr code to data.table. This takes 22 seconds on my machine, with the result showing how many times each price appears in the data.

```
library(dplyr)
library(dtplyr)
fake_data %>% 
  lazy_dt() %>%
  count(price, sort = TRUE)
```

Result

```
Source: local data table [3,000,000 x 2]
Call:   `_DT2`[, .(n = .N), keyby = .(price)][order(desc(n))]

    price     n
    <int> <int>
1 2586972    97
2 2843789    95
3  753207    92
4  809482    92
5 1735845    92
6  809659    90
# … with 2,999,994 more rows
```

---

If you need higher performance and don't mind a heuristic, you could also sample your data to make it 10% or 1% as big; if any placeholder values occur frequently in the whole data, they are also likely to be frequent in a random sample.

Answer (score 0):

I'd probably create price intervals, e.g. $0-50, $51-100, $101-150 etc.

**EDIT**: more comprehensive solutution

```
library(tidyverse)

df <- letters %>% 
  expand_grid(., .) %>% 
  rename(v1 = `....1`,
         v2 = `....2`) %>% 
  mutate(name = paste0(v1, v2)) %>% 
  select(name) %>% 
  bind_rows(., ., ., .)

df

n <- nrow(df)

df <- df %>% 
  mutate(price = rnorm(n = n, mean = 1000, sd = 200))

df %>% 
  ggplot(aes(x = price)) +
  geom_histogram()

df <- df %>% 
  mutate(price_grp = case_when(price < 500 ~ "$0-500",
                               price > 500 & price <= 1000 ~ "$501-1000",
                               price > 1000 & price <= 1500 ~ "$1001-1500",
                               price > 1500 ~ "+ $1500"))

df %>% 
  group_by(price_grp) %>% 
  summarize(occurences = n()) %>% 
  arrange(desc(occurences))
```

Comment: looking to find the values that occur the most unique, to identify potential placeholder prices that do no belong.

Comment: Yeah, sorry -- I was a bit brief. See edited answer